# Amount of time one has to spend in country issuing Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, international-travel

If I have a Schengen visa issued from Hungary for 20 days how many days do i have to stay in Hungary itself and how many may I travel outside of Hungary in the Schengen area? 
Additional info:

- I am Russian
- I will enter the EU in Austria
- I will exit the EU in Hungary
- Visa is issued by the embassy (Hungary) in Russia

Comment: You may have to enter the country that issued visa first (Hungary), as per schengen rules. https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf

Comment: @pbu There is no such rule, FAQ notwithstanding. But what in this document makes you think there is such a rule?

Comment: I am sorry apologies to OP, you are right @Relaxed. It says there `As a general rule you may cross any Schengen border with visa issued by any Schengen
country`.

Comment: Was your visa issued IN Hungary as you say (which would be a rather special situation, so please explain more about why that happened), or issued _somewhere else_ BY a Hungarian consulate/embassy?

Comment: @HenningMakholm im sorry for the confusion, i updated the question, thanks =)

Comment: There is no minimum duration of stay in Hungary under the Schengen rules.  However, if you change your itinerary from the one you presented in your application, you may be suspected of visa fraud.  The likelihood depends somewhat on the itinerary and on the nature of and reason for the change.  The question can't be answered in its present general form; I am voting to close as "too broad."